What's the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection equivalent to Autofac's registermodule?
// Here are used Autofac container
  public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
  {
    builder.RegisterModule(new MyClassModule
    {
       PropPrefix = "abc",
   });
}

I want to replace this piece of code using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
 public static IServiceCollection AddApiModules(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
 { 
    services.AddSingleton(new MyClassModule
    {
       PropPrefix = "abc",
   });
 }

Question is this two are the same and equivalent to each other ?

No. There are no modules in the .NET DI middleware. AddSingleton registers the specific object you provide as a singleton, nothing more. It doesn't expect that class to register other types, nor does it provide any events. If you want to bundle registrations you can create an extension method whose first parameter is IServiceCollection that registers what you want. That's how most packages work, eg builder.Services.UseHangfire registers the services needed by Hangfire

I need exact case, need to find equivalent way of registering using builder.RegisterModule in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection

What exact case do you refer to? The code you provided doesn't show what  your module does. .NET DI doesn't have modules. If you have a specific use case in mind there are probably ways to do what you want. Don't expect people familiar with .NET DI to guess what Autofac modules do

The simple module example in the Autofac docs can be implemented with an extension method. That's what all NuGet packages do - they provide an AddSomeFeature or UseSomeFeature method that bundles all their registrations in a single call. Instead of properties, you pass parameters  to the method

The equivalent to the AutoFac MyClassModule is the AddApiModules method. Without knowing what MyClassModule does though, it's hard to say what else should go into that method. I can only guess based on the Autofac documentation examples

are you still using Autofac? Or you are completely switching to the build in DI container?

I am going completely switch from Autofac container to Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection container and almost all services are changed to MS DI container, besides some piece of code where RegisterModule is used, so the question is if there is something equivalent to Autofac RegisterModule in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection ?
